# Is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash\{0\}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \langle x, n\rangle} / \lVert n \rVert^d$ discontinuous?

Tags: continuity, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I consider the following periodic function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash\{0\}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \langle x, n\rangle} }{\lVert n \rVert^d},$$
where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the usual $d$-dimensional scalar product.

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ is not a continuous function?

*Remark:* In dimension $d=1$, the function $f$ has a closed form expression, see this question: [Function with Fourier coefficient $1 / \lvert n \rvert$, $n \neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295285/function-with-fourier-coefficient-1-lvert-n-rvert-n-neq-0) We see that the function is discontinuous (and actually diverges) around the origin. My guess is that something similar is happening in any dimension $d\geq 1$.

Comment: For $d=2, x=0$ the series becomes $\sum_{(m,n) \ne (0,0)}{\frac{1}{m^2+n^2}}$ which is easily shown to be infinite

Comment: Right, but I don't see how to conclude. There exists continuous functions whose Fourier series do not converge. Here, you show that the partial series $S_N\{f\}(0) \rightarrow \infty$. How do we transfer this do $f$ itself?

Comment: I would say that for positive coefficients results like this that hold in one dimension (continuity at 0 of a cosine series implies absolute convergence if coefficients are positive) should generalize, but I may be wrong - a quick look around gave me a paper by Shapiro which has a lot of stuff about the topic, while Zygmund chapter 17 explains some of the specific stuff here - for example, rectangular vs spherical convergence, so it may be worth looking at if interested: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e5b0/c32a01d794bac0f77ac37b603bb07f80f323.pdf